# How to create Apache RewriteRule to rewrite if a file exists?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I am working with an .htaccess file I didn't write

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(foo|bar|baz|bof|x|y|z)(/.*)?$ $1.php
```

This rule corresponds with the existing .php files

- foo.php
- bar.php
- baz.php
- bof.php
- x.php
- y.php
- z.php

Is it possible I could write a catch-all rule but only rewrites if `$1.php` exists?

I'm trying something like this

```
RewriteRule ^(\w+)(/.*)?$ $1.php
```

However, consider this path

```
/helloworld/1/2/3 => helloworld.php
```

Problem here is helloworld.php does not exist. I do not want to rewrite this path.

I only want to rewrite **IF** the `$1.php` exists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prefix it with a RewriteCond

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(\w+).*$ $1.php
```

The `$1` is counter-intuitively available to the RewriteCond, because the RewriteRule matching (but not substitution) always happens first.

Comment: I updated the answer to make it a little more complete